# "union" over "group by cube"

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the UNION operator I'm trying to print department_id, job_id, AVG(salary) for:

- each department, and for each department, each job.
- each department, regardless of job.
- each job, regardless of department
- the entire table.

[image]

While this could be easily done with "group by cube"
**group by cube(a,b): (a,b) (a) (b) ()**, I'm tying to use the union operator to do this:

```
SELECT e.department_id, e.job_id, ROUND(AVG(e.salary))
FROM employees e
GROUP BY e.department_id, e.job_id
UNION
SELECT e.department_id, e.job_id, ROUND(AVG(e.salary))
FROM employees e;
```

In the second union, which is for "each departmemt, regardless of job" how do I group?

Comment: Replace job_id in second union with a dummy value or simply null. Then group only by department_id

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 'JOB PER DEPARTMENT' AS GROUP,
       A.DEPARTMENT_ID,
       B.JOB_ID,
       AVG(B.SALARY)
  FROM DEPARTMENTS A
  JOIN EMPLOYEES B
    ON A.DEPARTMENT_ID = B.DEPARTMENT_ID
 GROUP BY A.DEPARTMENT_ID, B.JOB_ID
UNION
SELECT 'DEPARTMENT' AS GROUP,
       A.DEPARTMENT_ID,
       'N/A' AS JOB_ID,
       AVG(B.SALARY)
  FROM DEPARTMENTS A
  JOIN EMPLOYEES B
    ON A.DEPARTMENT_ID = B.DEPARTMENT_ID
 GROUP BY A.DEPARTMENT_ID
UNION
SELECT 'JOB' AS GROUP,
       'N/A' AS DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       B.JOB_ID, 
       AVG(B.SALARY)
  FROM DEPARTMENT A
  JOIN EMPLOYEES B
    ON A.DEPARTMENT_ID = B.DEPARTMENT_ID
 GROUP BY A.JOB_ID
```